# Asynchronous function calls in Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, f#

Following version is calling all functions synchronously,

I'm looking to find out how to call asynchronous functions in parallel and return all `results` and `errors` to the caller.

**Request**

```
let requestAsync (url: string) : Async<Result<string, Error>> =
    async {
        Console.WriteLine ("Simulating request " + url)
        try
            do! Async.Sleep(1000)
            return Ok (url + ": body...")
        with :? WebException as e ->
            return Error {code = 500; message = "Internal Server Error";}
    }
```

**Test**

```
[<TestMethod>]
member this.TestrequestAsync() =
    let urls = [|
        "http://www.example.com/1";
        "http://www.example.com/2";
        "http://www.example.com/3";
        "http://www.example.com/4";
        "http://www.example.com/5";
        "http://www.example.com/6";
        "http://www.example.com/7";
        "http://www.example.com/8";
        "http://www.example.com/9";
        "http://www.example.com/10";
    |]

    urls
    |> Array.map (fun url -> requestAsync url |> Async.RunSynchronously) // Async.Parallel some mismatch

    // Iterate results
```

Ideally to be able to match `Ok` and `Error` results while iterating through results

**Edit** based on the answer.

```
let result =
    urls
    |> Seq.map Entity.requestDetailAsync2
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously


result
|> Array.iter Console.WriteLine // match x with Ok and Error?
```

**Attempt**

```
result |> Array.iter (fun data -> match data with
                                      | Ok result -> Console.WriteLine(result)
                                      | Error error -> Console.WriteLine(error) )
```

**Iteration using For in**

```
for r in result do
    match r with
    | Ok re -> Console.WriteLine(re)
    | Error error -> Console.WriteLine(error)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Async.Parallel` to run many async operations in parallel:

```
let results =
  urls
  |> Seq.map requestAsync   // seq<Async<'T>>
  |> Async.Parallel         // async<T' []>
  |> Async.RunSynchronously // T' []
```

[Here's a very similar example on MSDN.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/asynchronous-workflows#asynchronous-primitives)

There may be an issue with your `requestAsync` function return type, or a missing type definition in your example. Here's what I used to verify the solution:

```
type RequestError = {
  code : int
  message : string
}

let requestAsync (url: string) =
    async {
        Console.WriteLine ("Simulating request " + url)
        try
            do! Async.Sleep(1000)
            return Ok (url + ": body...")
        with :? WebException as e ->
            return Error {code = 500; message = "Internal Server Error";}
    }
```

Comment: thanks, Can you please add the portion for iteration, see my edit please

Comment: so if I were to explain the answer, you created a sequence of `requestAsync` calls and called all of them in parallel `Async.Parallel` and waited for them to finish `Async.RunSynchronously`

Comment: please see my attempt, do you agree with my attempt or is there a beautiful elegant solution?

Comment: @Developer11 your code that iteratively prints the results looks fine to me, though there are other ways to factor it e.g. you might find `for .. in .. do` reads better.

Comment: please check `for in` edit, is that how what you meant?